# Nodes order GetOrgChart, how to change?

Tags: getorgchart

How I can change the order of GetOrgChart nodes, I can't understand based on what it's ordering the nodes, I thought it's based on "id" but it's not working with me also.

Answer (score 1):

The node order is based on the node id. If you play around with the static JSON from one of their demos (http://www.getorgchart.com/Demos), you'll see that the order changes as you change the node id. At least that's what I'm seeing in both their demo and the dynamic data coming from my REST API.

btw, just to be sure, I added these pragmas on my page to eliminate the chance of browser caching:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

and we also add a query string param `ts=1521300615014` (or whatever the current time in milliseconds is) so the request doesn't get cached. Not sure if that's contributing to not seeing changes in the response.